# Why am I getting this error message in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

"The STAT command did not succeed. Error getting message number and sizes. Mail server pop3.live.com responded: Exceeded the login limit for a 15 minute period. Reduce the frequency of requests to the POP3 server."

Everything worked just fine and now I am getting this error message. Why is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Live POP3 allows only one login every 15 minutes. It basically connects, fetches mail and disconnects once the operation is done.

On the other hand IMAP connections can be kept open for more time. It looks like a restriction imposed by Live's mail server

Choose your live account and goto `Settings` and change the time interval to set it to **more than 15 minutes**. I am running IMAP, so ignore everything else in this screenshot except the one circled in red

[image: Thunderbird how to change Server settings]

Comment: @Jakob

Well, now the error message is gone, but the folders are messed up. There is just empty space where the folders names used to be....this is weird.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot. This change cannot cause any problems like that. If it does it is a bug unrelated to this solution

Comment: @Elysium If this answer is correct, then please mark it as solved